# How to return an empty response to an sms request?

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

How can I return nothing back to the twilio process after processing the sms message?

The examples in the api use the MessagingResponse and when that is used, it comes in as a Direction='reply' in the message log on the console.  This incurs an additional charge (inbound + reply).  Simply put, I want to do this..

```
app.post('/sms', (req, res) =>
{
    console.log('hello world');
}
```

without getting a 11200 error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try an empty string as the response message (Twilio needs you to return valid XML).

```
const http = require('http');
const express = require('express');
const MessagingResponse = require('twilio').twiml.MessagingResponse;

const app = express();

app.post('/sms', (req, res) => {
  const twiml = new MessagingResponse();

  // twiml.message('');

  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/xml'});
  res.end(twiml.toString());
});

http.createServer(app).listen(1337, () => {
  console.log('Express server listening on port 1337');
});
```

Comment: No, this produces 14103 - Invalid Body

Comment: It should work, anyway, try to comment out `// twiml.message('')`. The idea is that your TwiML response should be just `<Response></Response>` or `<Response />` (a blank response tag).

Answer (score 2):

Answer from Twilio docs:

> In order to receive incoming messages, without sending an auto-response, the Twilio app should respond with a simple empty Response - `<Response></Response>`.

https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223134127-Receive-SMS-and-MMS-Messages-without-Responding